# SSRS don't show duplicate row data, just the unique value in the column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report where row data can have the same data, apart from the data in the last column. Just adding the data to a table results in this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1111 | 234345 |
| 1 | def | 2222 | 435656 |
| 1 | def | 2222 | 423233 |
| 1 | xyz | 1234 | 145423 |

I want to show the data like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1111 | 234345 |
| 1 | def | 2222 | 435656 |
|  |  |  | 423233 |
| 1 | xyz | 1234 | 145423 |

I've tried adding a row inside the group and grouping by Column 4, but this results in:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1111 |  |
|  |  |  | 234345 |
| 1 | def | 2222 |  |
|  |  |  | 435656 |
|  |  |  | 423233 |
| 1 | xyz | 1234 |  |
|  |  |  | 145423 |

I want the first values of column 4 on the same row as the data, and only the "additional" Column 4 values on a row by themselves below.
How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a table and not a matrix then you need to create a rowgroup to group by the first three columns only. You also need to make sure that your fourth column is in the details rowgroup.

This will give you the desired results.

Comment: I've tried adding the first 3 columns as parent groups, which worked, but now the first column only shows once as it is the same value for all rows. I tried removing the first column from the group but that didn't work.

Comment: it sounds like you have added a group for each column? Based on your sample you should only have 2 rowgroups, the first should group by the 1st 3 cols and the details group with no grouping. It might be easier if you create a table from scratch rather than editing your existing one in case there are some left over properties on the columns. If this does not help, show a screen shot of the report design and row groups and I'll post a better answer